# Using bitmasks with iOS to send and receive data

Tags: ios, xcode, bit-masks

I am working on a project where one of the requirements is to send and receive data using bitmasks. I have 12 bits (12 pieces of data) that I have to transmit the status of.  I have an elementary understanding of bitmasks.  Does anyone have a good example of using bitmasks with iOS to send and receive data?  I am well versed on how to send data, I'm just not sure how to assemble and read the bitmask.  Thanks.

Comment: More information is needed. In general values are generally obtained from bitmasks using logical ands `&` of a bitmak and as necessary shifting '>>' or '<<'.

Answer (score 1):

It's really easy to manipulate true bitmasks in Swift 2.0: just make an OptionSetType. Nice example in the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_OptionSetType_Protocol/index.html

Comment: And if you want to play with an _existing_ OptionSetType, pick something like UIViewAutoresizing.

Comment: And of course modesty will never prevent me from suggesting that you just might try reading _my_ explanation: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#SECoptionsSets